# Deploying Monodroid App to device always fails on the first attempt

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm developing a Monodroid app and whenever I do a clean debug deployment (first wiping and uninstalling any previous installation from the phone, then hitting F5 to debug) the initial attempt to load the app in a debug session always crashes.  The debug session ends.  Then I do the same thing again, hit F5 and this time it loads fine.  I have not found any exceptions being thrown during the initial load.  Has anybody else experienced this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Visual Studio or MonoDevelop?

Try disabling "Fast deployment" in the project property page.

Comment: I'm using VS2010. Thanks. Okay, I'll give that a shot and reply back with results.

Comment: Yes, disabling Fast Deployment seems to eliminate that initial crash when installing for the first time.  Of course, as one would assume, it does take longer to deploy. I'm not sure which I prefer, the fast crash or the slow deploy. I guess I could switch it off whenever I do a clean install which is not that often compared to re-installs during debug debug sessions. Thanks.